Should I interleave sin and cosine in sinusoidal positional encoding?
I'm trying to implement a sinusoidal positional encoding. I found two solutions that give different encodings. I am wondering if one of them is wrong or both are correct. I showcase visual figures of the resulting encodings for both options. Thank you :)
class SinusoidalPosEmb(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.dim = dim
    def forward(self, x):
        device = x.device
        half_dim = self.dim // 2
        emb = math.log(10000) / (half_dim - 1)
        emb = torch.exp(torch.arange(half_dim, device=device) * -emb)
        emb = x[:, None] * emb[None, :]
        emb = torch.cat((emb.sin(), emb.cos()), dim=-1)
        return emb


2)
class TransformerPositionalEmbedding(nn.Module):
    """
    From paper "Attention Is All You Need", section 3.5
    """
    def __init__(self, dimension, max_timesteps=1000):
        super(TransformerPositionalEmbedding, self).__init__()
        assert dimension % 2 == 0, "Embedding dimension must be even"
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.pe_matrix = torch.zeros(max_timesteps, dimension)
        # Gather all the even dimensions across the embedding vector
        even_indices = torch.arange(0, self.dimension, 2)
        # Calculate the term using log transforms for faster calculations
        # (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891595/pow-vs-exp-performance)
        log_term = torch.log(torch.tensor(10000.0)) / self.dimension
        div_term = torch.exp(even_indices * -log_term)
        # Precompute positional encoding matrix based on odd/even timesteps
        timesteps = torch.arange(max_timesteps).unsqueeze(1)
        self.pe_matrix[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(timesteps * div_term)
        self.pe_matrix[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(timesteps * div_term)
    def forward(self, timestep):
        # [bs, d_model]
        return self.pe_matrix[timestep]


